# Future without a type - what does it mean?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is returning a `Future` without a type means `Future<void>`?

```
Future validateUsername(String value) async {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Future` with no explicit type argument is shorthand for `Future<dynamic>`.

In general, if no type argument is specified, the least constrained type allowed is assumed.  For most generics, that means `dynamic`.  In cases where the generic constrains the type argument, that means that constraining base type.  For example, given:

```dart
class Foo {}

class Generic<T extends Foo> {}
```

then `Generic` without any explicit type argument would be shorthand for `Generic<Foo>`.

Comment: I'm not a Dart user, but I'm curious: does `Future<dynamic>` impose or imply any kind of runtime overhead that a `Future<void>` or `Future<Null>` avoids? (i.e. should `Future<void>` or `Future<Null>` always be preferred over `Future` and `Future<dynamic>`?)

Comment: @Dai If, after `await`ing the `Future`, you don't do anything with the result, then it shouldn't make any runtime difference.  However, you still should prefer `Future<void>` over `Future<dynamic>` (and over `Future<Null>`) because `Future<void>` provides better compile-time type safety: it will prevent callers from accidentally attempting to do something with `Future`'s result.

Answer (score 1):

If no type is specified as generic type `dynamic` is used. So it means `Future<dynamic>`.

You can check it inside [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev) (or any IDE):

[image: dartpad future]